# Connecting to Internet via 3 Raspberry Pi Bridges - Can ping, but can't load in browser

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, bridge, wireless-bridge

I have a setup as follows:

```
                Internet
                    |
                    |                                                           192.168.0.3
PC1                 |                                                             Laptop1                                                  
   |---------------Switch(Gateway)---------------Pi1-------Pi2---------Pi3------------|
PC2                192.168.0.1              192.168.0.*(DHCP)     192.168.0.2     Laptop2                  
                                                                                192.168.0.4
```

From the laptops I can ping external websites such as '176.34.131.233' (DuckDuckGo), however when I attempt to connect to these servers via a browser (by pasting the IP address in the URL bar) I get 'Server not found'.

From the desktops everything works perfectly fine.

So obviously the problem must lie in the Pi or the laptops.

The laptops are not running DNS hence pasting the IP into the URL.

I have noticed on wireshark that the laptops are able to complete a 3 way handshake (SYN > SYN, ACK> ACK), but for some reason it seems to complete 2 (with same dst port and different src ports).

Upon completion of the handshakes the connection is immediately terminated by a FIN, ACK from the laptop followed by a normal closing connection of another FIN, ACK from the server then a final ACK (This closing of connections is also duplicated across the 2 different ports).

No HTTP GET packets are sent to the server.

The Pi are running bridging software I wrote myself in python which judging by the fact the laptops can ping external servers and the 3 way handshakes can be completed, it seems the software works.

So the question is why on earth are there 2 sets of 3 way handshakes going on and why can I ping a website, but not load it in my browser?

If anybody has any ideas or suggestions it would be most appreciated.

My thoughts are is either the way the laptop has been configured (Running linux), some kind of firewall in the router blocking the data or something fundamentally wrong with my code. I have looked into all with no avail.

Comment: Can you explain how the pi's are connected and what you mean by bridging. Do you maybe mean rebroadcasting?

Comment: All through wireless interfaces, by bridging I mean that the Pis are acting as a network bridge.

Pi1 is connected to the switch as you would connect your laptop to an acccess point. There are then adhoc connections between the Pis and the Pi3s far interface is an access point for the laptops to connect to.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridging_(networking)

Comment: Do each of your Pi devices have 2  wireless interfaces? If not, you are not bridging, you are repeating. This could explain multiple identical packets.

Comment: Yes there are 2 interfaces on each, thanks for the help, it really is appreciated! But gronostaj hit the nail on the head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is probably the core of your issue:

> The laptops are not running DNS hence pasting the IP into the URL.

When a browser requests a document over HTTP, it sends the `Host` header which specifies the domain that is requested. This header is useful for running "virtual hosts", that is hosting multiple websites on single IP address. Web server checks the incoming `Host` header to determine which website client attempts to contact and handles the request accordingly.

Entering IP address directly into browser's address bar results in no `Host` header being sent. If the server is configured to run in virtual hosts setup (which is pretty common even for servers hosting single site), it won't be able to determine which virtual host you're attempting to connect to and it will reply with some generic error response like 404.

If you don't want to use real DNS, there's a simple workaround: add actual domain to the `hosts` file. You haven't specified what kind of OS is running on problematic machines, so here's a generic guide. The `hosts` file is located in `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows and `/etc/hosts` on Linux (see Wikipedia for a [more comprehensive list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#Location_in_the_file_system)). It's a plain text file, but you'll need administrative privileges to edit it. Just append a line in format `<ip> <domain>` at the end, for example:

```
151.101.193.69 superuser.com
```

Save the file. This entry will override DNS resolution for this domain. All HTTP clients that use OS-provided DNS will now resolve `superuser.com` to `151.101.193.69`, so browsers will send proper `Host` headers.

Comment: You absolute hero, that was exactly the problem!

Comment: I will just need to get DNS working correctly then